# php send mail with attachment

Tags: php, email, sendmail

here is code for send mail,

```
<?php
    $owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
    $headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
    $subject = 'Visitor : ' . $_POST["name"];
    $messageBody = "";

    if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: '. $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }else{
        $headers = '';
    }
    if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
        $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
        $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }   

    if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Message: '."\n". $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    }

    if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
        $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
    }

    try{
        if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
            throw new Exception('mail failed');
        }else{
            echo 'mail sent';
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
?>
```

how to implement attachment with this code, i have tried by seeing some samples on stack overflow and other sites it doesnt seems to work.. help on this please..

Comment: which type of attachment you want to send with mail?

Comment: `it doesnt seems to work` care to elaborate?

Comment: Why not use some opensource library like https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.phpmailer.php   PHPMailer which is well documented and handles these operations pretty easily.

Comment: dox file and pdf files

Comment: First error: end your lines by \r\n, second create hash boundaries, split your attachment in base64 chunks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760817/send-email-with-pdf-attachment

Comment: This code can be abused as a spam gateway and to send phishing mails. The part beginning with `if($_POST["stripHTML"] ==` is super useless, everyone can set it to whatever he wants and on true you would strip your own HTML, too. Sending mails is even more sensitive than SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://phpmailer.worxware.com/
Here is attachments example http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail

Simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

A working code:

```
<?php 
//define the receiver of the email 
$to = 'youraddress@example.com'; 
//define the subject of the email 
$subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
//create a boundary string. It must be unique 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com"; 
//add boundary string and mime type specification 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.pdf'))); 
//define the body of the message. 
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="attachment.pdf"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This if working for me to send file as attachments.

```
<?php
    if($value == "Send")                     // Submit button
    {
        $fileName = $_REQUEST['file'];      

        $to = $_REQUEST['Email'];   
        $subject = "PHP File Manager";
        $message = "download the attached file";
        # Open a file
        $downloadfile = $fileName;
        $file = fopen($downloadfile, "r" );
        if( $file == false )
        {
        echo "Error in opening file";
        exit();
        }

        # Read the file into a variable
        $size = filesize($downloadfile);
        $content = fread( $file, $size);

        # encode the data for safe transit
        # and insert \r\n after every 76 chars.
        $encoded_content = chunk_split( base64_encode($content));

        # Get a random 32 bit number using time() as seed.
        $num = md5( time() );
        $SendEmail ="test@gmail.com";
        $header = 'From: ' . $SendEmail . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $SendEmail . "\r\n"; 

        # Define the main headers.
        //$header = "From:Test\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
        $header .= "boundary=$num\r\n";
        $header .= "--$num\r\n";

        # Define the message section
        $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n\n";
        $header .= "$message\r\n";
        $header .= "--$num\r\n";

        # Define the attachment section
        $header .= "Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; ";
        $header .= "name=\"$fileName\"\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
        $header .= "filename=\"$fileName\"\r\n\n";
        $header .= "$encoded_content\r\n";
        $header .= "--$num--";

        # Send email now
        $retval = mail ( $to, $subject, "", $header );
        if( $retval == true )
        {
            echo "success";
        }
    }
?>
```